# Adding 'Add to Cart' to 'Collection Products' view

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I want to add an Add to Cart button to my products when they are still in the Collection Products view (Category overview). By default, when you navigate to a category like `/commerce_kickstart/product-category/sample-category-1`, you will find the single products display like this:

[image]

I would like to have all of the single products be shown like this:

[image]

In the Product Display content type, the add-to-cart-form is stored in `$content` variable. It is pretty easy to access via `field_product`and I can for example add multiple forms and stuff. But how can I get the form in the Collections Product view? 
I went to Structure -> Views -> Collection Products -> Field and looked through the available fields. I found `field_product` but when I add this, everthing that changes is that a link to the product is shown underneath the price.

So how can I add this to the Category overview?

Edit:

I have added this field (because the name appeared to be familiar scince the cart form is stored in this variable (`field_product`) in `node--product_display`

https: //i.stack.imgur.com/CaNo9.png

And that caused this to appear, wich only adds a link to the product underneath the price.

https: //i.stack.imgur.com/1vbWW.png

And this is basically all the configuration besides some more irrelevant stuff:

https: //i.stack.imgur.com/fk9BB.png

Comment: In your view's field_product, do you not see the option "add to cart" under "Formatter"? Can you add a screenshot of your view configuration page?

Comment: @longboardnode I have added the screens (Sorry for plain text links, cant post more than 2 due to lack of reputation in this community)

Comment: In your view, can you add a relationship to the product category in your cart? It should be visible as Referenced Entity or Referenced Product... basically in views you need to join your node/product to its related store/product, once you have done that you should see an available field "% to buy" with the formatter "add to cart button"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAE5W.jpg You are a lifesaver, I would have never been able to find it myself

Comment: Good to hear it worked! I added as answer, plz accept if was helpful.

Comment: Sure thing. Keep an eye out for me if you want to play lifesaver again, I am afraid this is not going to be my last question scince I cant really get a hold of Drupal ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, can you add a relationship to the product category in your cart? It should be visible as Referenced Entity or Referenced Product... basically in views you need to join your node/product to its related store/product, once you have done that you should see an available field "% to buy" with the formatter "add to cart button"